# Passing an objective-c protocol delegate as a parameter

Tags: ios, objective-c, paypal

When I pass an objective-c protocol as a parameter, when and that delegate is then used to trigger one of its methods, the method does not fire.

I'm using the delegate from the [Paypal iOS SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK) defined as follows:

```
@protocol PayPalPaymentDelegate <NSObject>
    - (void)payPalPaymentDidCancel:(PayPalPaymentViewController *)paymentViewController;
@end
```

I have a UIViewController that implements the protocol:

```
//simpleviewcontroller.h
@interface SimpleViewController : UIViewController<PayPalPaymentDelegate>
```

and a method signature like the following:

```
// HelperFunctions.m
+ (void) doSomething: (id<PayPalPaymentDelegate>)paypalDelegate
{
    // the selector 'payPalPaymentDidCancel' DOES fire
    [paypalDelegate performSelector:@selector(payPalPaymentDidCancel:) withObject:self]
}


// called from simpleviewcontroller.m that implements PayPalPaymentDelegate
[HelperFunctions doSomething: self]
```

The problem is that when paypal returns the result, it does not trigger the delegate:

```
// code inside of the 'success' block of an AFNetworking call
PayPalPaymentViewController *paymentViewController;
paymentViewController = [[PayPalPaymentViewController alloc] initWithPayment:payment    
                                                             configuration:paypalConfiguration   
                                                             delegate:paypalDelegate];
```

The paypalDelegate passed to 'delegate' here is never triggered by paypal. Whereas it IS triggered if done from simpleviewcontroller.m and not via the method doSomething

Comment: I think you should also pass the SimpleViewController since delegate method also requires the view controller. It's working on SimpleViewController since you're passing "him", but it's not working since you're passing "HelperFunctions" object. (Oh wait, the delegate! Just use paypalDelegate instead of self.)

Comment: On the line where you write `[paypalDelegate performSelector:@selector(payPalPaymentDidCancel:) withObject:self];`, what is the `self` meant to refer to? It's inside a class method, after all.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have created the `paymentViewController` are you keeping hold of the `paypalDelegate` somewhere? `PayPalPaymentViewController` only keeps a weak reference to the delegate so if not it will be being released (and therefore none of it's methods firing) by ARC at the end of the scope that creates the `PayPalPaymentViewController`.

Comment: I'm not storing the paypalDelegate in any variable at all, simply passing Self to the method doSomething. Should I create a strong variable and put paypalDelegate into it? Note that using performSelector inside the method _does_ work, so wouldn't this suggest that the delegate's reference is not being lost?

Comment: is the code that creates the `PayPalPaymentViewController` in the `doSomething:` method? Though I assume you're view controller (the delegate) is in the view controller hierarchy and so probably not being released? Put a log in the `dealloc` method of the delegate object and just check that it is not being released.